# How to parse a slice of u16 input with nom?

Tags: rust, nom

Given a raw input stream of `&[u16]` how can I use nom to parse it taking into account that nom expects `&str` as input?

For instance, given the following data:

```
pub const RAW_INPUT: &[u16] = &[102, 111, 111];
```

I want to parse it into the string "foo".

Comment: Are you sure that you have a slice of u16? Utf-8 characters are represented by u8 values.

Comment: Are you trying to parse UTF-16?

Comment: I am parsing raw date from modbus. In modbus all registers are u16.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could go about doing this. I don't know anything about modbus, so I'm assuming that the input looks like your `RAW_INPUT` above. First, you can use `as` to cast the u16 to u8. This will silently truncate values larger than 255. The other, safer approach is to use [std::convert::TryFrom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html):

> Simple and safe type conversions that may fail in a controlled way under some circumstances. It is the reciprocal of `TryInto`.
>
> This is useful when you are doing a type conversion that may trivially succeed but may also need special handling. For example, there is no way to convert an `i64` into an `i32` using the `From` trait, because an `i64` may contain a value that an `i32` cannot represent and so the conversion would lose data. This might be handled by truncating the `i64` to an `i32` (essentially giving the `i64`'s value modulo `i32::MAX`) or by simply returning `i32::MAX`, or by some other method. The `From` trait is intended for perfect conversions, so the `TryFrom` trait informs the programmer when a type conversion could go bad and lets them decide how to handle it.

Some illustrative code you can play around with on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91d06730822f00a39de8e2a6679c7a31):

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::convert::TryFrom;
    use std::num::TryFromIntError;
    use std::str;

    pub const RAW_BAD_INPUT: &[u16] = &[102, 111, 111, 300];
    pub const RAW_GOOD_INPUT: &[u16] = &[102, 111, 111];

    /// Converts using `as`. Demonstrates truncation.
    #[test]
    fn test_truncating() {
        let expected = vec![102, 111, 111, 44];  // Note: 44
        let actual = RAW_BAD_INPUT
            .iter()
            .map(|val| *val as u8)
            .collect::<Vec<u8>>();
        assert_eq!(expected, actual);
    }

    /// Demonstrates conversion using `TryFrom` on input with values that
    /// would be truncated
    #[test]
    fn test_try_from_bad() {
        let actual: Vec<Result<u8, TryFromIntError>> =
            RAW_BAD_INPUT.iter().map(|val| u8::try_from(*val)).collect();

        assert_eq!(actual[0].unwrap(), 102u8);
        assert_eq!(actual[1].unwrap(), 111u8);
        assert_eq!(actual[2].unwrap(), 111u8);
        assert!(actual[3].is_err());
    }

    /// Demonstrates conversion using `TryFrom` on input with values
    /// that would not be truncated. Also parses the Vec<u8> as a UTF-8
    /// encoded string
    #[test]
    fn test_try_from_ok() {
        let intermediate: Vec<u8> = RAW_GOOD_INPUT
            .iter()
            .map(|val| u8::try_from(*val).unwrap())
            .collect();
        let actual = match str::from_utf8(&intermediate) {
            Ok(s) => s,
            Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8: {}", e),
        };
        assert_eq!("foo", actual);
    }
}
```

Using the code in `test_try_from_ok`, you should now have a `String` containing the data you wish to parse with `nom`.

Comment: This... doesn't appear to use [nom](https://crates.io/crates/nom), as the OP requests.

Comment: I'd be interesting in understanding  the reason for the down vote here. My reading of the OP's question was that they were not able to use the library they wanted to use because they were dealing with type `&[u16]`. I've shown a few ways they can convert to `Vec<u8>` or `String`, which they then should be able to use with `nom`.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
pub const RAW_INPUT: &[u16] = &[102, 111, 111];
```

I ended up converting the input to `u8` first:

```
let xs = RAW_INPUT
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|x| x.to_be_bytes().to_vec())
    .collect::<Vec<u8>>();
```

And then parsing it normally with nom.